# How to call a function which is in a overwritten controller block?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, controllers

I have developed a module to overwrite a controller. 
I have the next route:
Lecasa/Javinewlistproductcontroller/Block/Catalog/Product/List.phtml

This List.phtml file is:
class Lecasa_Javinewlistproductcontroller_Block_Catalog_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List

I have been trying to use a function that I created in this List.phtml but i did not find the way to call it. Then I copied this one in Lecasa/Javinewlistproductcontroller/Helper/Data.php, I configured all files but when I used Mage::helper(...)->function(), the magento system added the Mage_ prefix to the helper class. Then, as a last alternative, I would like to know how I can call the function which is created at Lecasa/Javinewlistproductcontroller/Block/Catalog/Product/List.phtml
directly from the rwd/.../List.phtml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should rename your file for your block to `List.php`, .phtml is the ending for templates.

In order to overwrite the Magento block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` you should add a rewrite tag into your modules `config.xml` in the global section:

```
<blocks>            
     <catalog>              
          <rewrite>                                                
              <product_list>Lecasa_Javinewlistproductcontroller_Block_Catalog_Product_List</product_list>               
          </rewrite>            
       </catalog>       
</blocks>
```

With this done you can use your method everywhere a block of type   `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` is available, for example in a product list template using `$this->yourMethod()`.

If you want to add your new block to the layout you don't need to add the above rewrite. You can just a `<block type="yourmodule/catalog_product_list" template="...">` into an appropriate layout xml file. Then you can use your method in the configured template via `$this->yourMethod()`

I hope that helps